# override to_s while keeping output of inspect

Tags: ruby, oop, overriding

i override the to_s method to get pretty output when i use puts but at the same time i seem to loose my ability to inspect the object. Is there a way to get the normal output of inspect while overriding to_s ?

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :first, :last, :birthdate
  def initialize(first=nil, last=nil, birthdate=nil)
    @first, @last, @birthdate = first, last, birthdate
  end
  def age
    if birthdate
      Time.now.year-birthdate
    else
      0
    end
  end
  def to_s
    "#{@first} #{@last} (#{age})"
  end
end

me = Person.new("Peter", "Marien", 1962)
p me  >>Peter Marien (50)
p me.inspect  >>"Peter Marien (50)"

#Need #<Person:0x1ec2550 @first="Peter", @last="Marien", @birthdate=1962>
```

Comment: This bug report talks about the same issue: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4453 however I don't see any progress on the ticket.

Comment: so it's a bug, didn't realize that.., thanks for the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby documentation [clearly states](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Object%3ainspect), that by default `inspect` uses `to_s` as its output.

If you don't need the address of the object, you could provide your own inspect, to have almost the same behavior:

```
class Person
  def inspect
    vars = self.instance_variables.
      map{|v| "#{v}=#{instance_variable_get(v).inspect}"}.join(", ")
    "<#{self.class}: #{vars}>"
  end
end
```

But you could also install a gem called `awesome_print` that will give very nice output.
First in console:

```
$ gem install awesome_print
```

then in irb or your script:

```
require 'awesome_print'
ap Person.new("John")
```

There is also a built-in `pp` library, which have similar purpose. Still it is not immune (at least in Ruby 1.9.2-p290) to overriding of `to_s`.

A quick example of `pp`:

```
require 'pp'
pp Person.new("John")
```

Comment: thanks but...
p (or puts) DOESN't give the same result unaltered and your code gives the following result, so the to_s prettifier no longer works..
#<Person:0x1d2e6d8>
"#<Person:0x1d2e6d8>"

Comment: Could you elaborate? - I don't know what is the expected behavior vs the behavior of the code provided.

Comment: just try it with a more complex object, p object gives other output than object.inspect, anyway, your code doesn't work, have you tried it ? it gives both the object representation, not the prettyfied and the object representation

Comment: thanks, a step in the right direction, but not completely, i put the result in an answer where i can give layout

Comment: This fails if there are circular references, e.g.: husband = Person.new; wife = Person.new; husband.spouse = wife; wife.spouse = husband

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by default inspect uses the to_s method.

However, you could also override inspect, including aliasing the old to_s method to it before overriding.

Comment: You want to use alias_method (look it up) to "save a copy" of the old to_s method, and then override the inspect method to simply call the old to_s method. You might also be able to just use alias_method to alias the old to_s to "inspect" before overriding to_s -- if that works it is the simplest way.

Comment: that doesn't work Perry, tried all the combinations with alias and alias_method, either you get the prettified output for both or the non-prettified for both

Comment: I suggested essentially the same thing the other person answering gave, with some small variations. I think you're probably not quite doing it right -- perhaps you should post the code you tried out.

Comment: This does not work.  The default #to_s does not include the instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here the sollution of Aleksander, the first p should give the overridden to_s but doesn't, you have to explictly call to_s like in the second p to get the result i want. I'm also not sure this inspect will give the same result as the original one with more complex objects, i'll try it at home. Anyone a still better shot ?
I'm aware of the awesome_print gem but IMHO for something basic like this you shouldn't need to include gems.

```
class Person

  def initialize(first=nil, last=nil, birthdate=nil) 
    @first, @last, @birthdate = first, last, birthdate 
  end 

  # New implementation of to_s 
  def to_s 
    "#{@first} #{@last}" 
  end

  def inspect 
    vars = self.instance_variables. 
      map{|v| "#{v}=#{instance_variable_get(v).inspect}"}.join(", ") 
    "<#{self.class}: #{vars}>" 
  end 

end 

me = Person.new("John")
p me         #--><Person: @first="John", @last=nil, @birthdate=nil>
p me.to_s    #-->"John "
p me.inspect #-->"<Person: @first=\"John\", @last=nil, @birthdate=nil>"
```

Edit: i just tried awesome_print and i'm pleased, was afraid i had to use IRB to make use of it but it isn't, i run my scripts in my editor namely

```
require 'awesome_print'
ap me --> 
#<Person:0x027efe20
    @birthdate = nil,
    @first = "John",
    @last = nil
>
```

Edit, using pretty_print as suggested by Aleksander, doesn't interfere with the overridden to_s

```
require 'PP'
class Person

  def initialize(first=nil, last=nil, birthdate=nil) 
    @first, @last, @birthdate = first, last, birthdate 
  end 

  # New implementation of to_s 
  def to_s 
    "#{@first} #{@last}" 
  end
end 

me = Person.new("John")
pp me                   #--> <Person: @first="John", @last=nil, @birthdate=nil>
warn me.pretty_inspect  #--> <Person: @first="John", @last=nil, @birthdate=nil>
```

Comment: Re: `awesome_print` there is also `pp` (pretty_print) library which is bundled with Ruby and have similar purpose.

Comment: But `pp` is based on inspect, so changing `to_s` will spoil result of `pp`. This doesn't happen with `awesome_print`, which is why I recommend its usage.

Comment: tried pp and pretty_inspect, they don't inter-fear with the overridden to_s, and it's in the kernel which is good but you do have to require it, edit the answer for future reference and gonna mark your response as answer, thanks for the help

Comment: Strange - I tried the example you have provided, and have a different result. Which Ruby version do you use? Also: do you require 'PP' or 'pp'?

Comment: ruby -v gives ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32], require 'pp' gives the same result as require 'PP', could there be a difference ?
Maybe it's the OS, i use Windows 7

Comment: `require 'PP'` and `require 'pp'` gives different result on Linux, so if you wish to write portable scripts use only the second form. I checked the example on 1.9.3 and `pp` still is not immune to `to_s` overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Perry, here one of the many combinations i tried to get alias or alias_method to work, if you think this works, can you submit a working snippet ?

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :first, :last, :birthdate
  def initialize(first=nil, last=nil, birthdate=nil)
    @first, @last, @birthdate = first, last, birthdate
  end

  alias old_to_s to_s
  def inspect
    old_to_s
  end
  def to_s
    "#{@first} #{@last}"
  end

end

me = Person.new("Peter")
p me         #-->#<Person:0x1da26b8>
p me.inspect #-->"#<Person:0x1da26b8>"
```